# Apache Lucene createWeight() for wildcard query

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I'm using Apache Lucene 6.6.0 and I'm trying to extract terms from the search query. Current version of code looks like this:

```
Query parsedQuery = new AnalyzingQueryParser("", analyzer).parse(query);
Weight weight = parsedQuery.createWeight(searcher, false);
Set<Term> terms = new HashSet<>();
weight.extractTerms(terms);
```

It works pretty much fine, but recently I noticed that it doesn't support queries with wildcards (i.e. `*` sign). If the query contains wildcard(s), then I get an exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query
>   id:123*456 does not implement createWeight    at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.Query.createWeight(Query.java:66)    at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.createWeight(IndexSearcher.java:751)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.(BooleanWeight.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.createWeight(BooleanQuery.java:225)

So is there a way to use `createWeight()` with wildcarded queries? Or maybe there's another way to extract search terms from query without `createWeight()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, it is necessary to rewrite the query, for example, as follows:

```
final AnalyzingQueryParser analyzingQueryParser = new AnalyzingQueryParser("", analyzer);

// TODO: The rewrite method can be overridden.
// analyzingQueryParser.setMultiTermRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.CONSTANT_SCORE_BOOLEAN_REWRITE);

Query parsedQuery = analyzingQueryParser.parse(query);
// Here parsedQuery is an instance of the org.apache.lucene.search.WildcardQuery class.

parsedQuery = parsedQuery.rewrite(reader);
// Here parsedQuery is an instance of the org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper class.

final Weight weight = parsedQuery.createWeight(searcher, false);
final Set<Term> terms = new HashSet<>();
weight.extractTerms(terms);
```

Please refer to the thread:

- Nabble: [Lucene - Java Users - How to get the terms matching a WildCardQuery in Lucene 6.2?](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-terms-matching-a-WildCardQuery-in-Lucene-6-2-td4302799.html)
- Mail archive: [How to get the terms matching a WildCardQuery in Lucene 6.2?](https://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg48071.html)

for further details.

It seems the mentioned Stack Overflow question is this one: [How to get matches from a wildcard Query in Lucene 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074057/how-to-get-matches-from-a-wildcard-query-in-lucene-6-2).

Comment: Well, it looks for me as some kind of a black-magic, but it actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: @DmytroTitov, glad it has helped! Agree with you: this is not straightforward.